# Facebook page activity feed

Tags: php, facebook

We want to add an activity feed for a Facebook page as a widget to our Wordpress blog. This seems like it should be a simple thing to do, the Facebook documentation refuses to yield the relevant description though. It seems like 'perhaps' an app is required, although maybe not...

Any tips much appreciated.

Toby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab an RSS feed from a facebook page through the graph API; which will be written in XML

Edit:

Most of the necessary steps are outlined here: http://sem-group.net/search-engine-optimization-blog/subscribe-to-your-favorite-facebook-page-via-rss/

Although you'll need to get the id of your page as part of the steps above.

To get Facebook page id: http://rieglerova.net/how-to-get-a-facebook-fan-page-id/

Wordpress seems to have its own specific plugin for importing RSS feeds:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rss-import/

(P.S. IF you find that this answers your question would there be any chance you could accept it?)

Comment: Thanks - can you provide any more details/links?

Comment: Thanks for that - it's not quite what we're after, but it might do! I'll definitely accept if nothing else turns up, we're hoping for something that separates out post images. Thanks.

Comment: PS Accepted, but if anyone has information on how to do this using the Graph API, that would be great.